# C# multiple version binding at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, binding, dependencies

The software I work on is written in dot net C# with netframework 4.7.2 and uses a 3rd party Framework that I call : "Frameworkv9".

Frameworkv9 is long to install.

Editor of Frameworkv9 ask me to test Frameworkv10.

When testing Frameworkv10 with my app already built I have a runtime error that I solve by adding in app.config :

```
        <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Framework" publicKeyToken="b79850feedbeef" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

I commit the code and the software works and loads succesfully Frameworkv10
But i want to rollback, so I uninstall Frameworkv10 and reinstall Frameworkv9.

My issue is now that the bindingredirect is set in the app.config, the CLR looks only to find v10 which is not anymore there and thus fails to load the v9 which is there, resulting the full software to crash.

==> My question is: Can i instruct in anyway in my app.config some directive to have at runtime the possibility to run Frameworkv9 or Frameworkv10 ? (to be compliant with the Open/Closed principle, haha)

Idea behind is to not modify source code and to be flexible enough to test different versions of third party dependency without needing to rebuild (the real project imply a nuget package which is an adapter to the 3rd party dlls -so update of framework needs rebuild / repush nuget package-)

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: netframework 4.7.2

Comment: Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection